# Should an interface contain its own callback class?

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

If I have an interface with multiple callbacks, that I'd like to be used either as a complete set or individually. Can I simply create the needed class inside the interface? Or should I make it static and move it to another class?

Example of what I mean in code:

```
public interface SomeChangeListener {

void OnSomeChangeA();

void OnSomeChangeB();


class SomeCallback implements SomeChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void OnSomeChangeA() {}

    @Override
    public void OnSomeChangeB() {}
}}
```

This works well, I'm only concerned about any flaws in it, that will cause issues at some point. Memory leaks etc...

Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a class definition into an interface ... should not cause a memory leak. Like: never.

Or in other words: if you manage to put down a class definition that leads to some memory leak, than that leak is caused by things your code is doing. Not by the fact that it is part of some byte code belonging to some class here or there!

Thus the **flaw** that really matters here is: typically, interfaces are used to create an **abstraction** from concrete implementations. Putting one implementation directly into your interface somehow contradicts that goal! See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131332/what-is-the-point-of-an-interface) for example.

Long story short: you can do that; but I think it carries a certain "bad design" smell.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't sure if it was the correct thing to do, memory leaks are not something I totally understand. So what will and won't cause them is sort of always on my mind. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Answered back to fast, sorry. I'm guessing just moving it to a static inner class on my base class will be the best thing to do. As I was doing it, I knew there was something odd about it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the quick accept. But please note: this is simply a topic where many valid opinions exist. So, my advise is: best you directly talk to people that have some experience. Have them review larger parts of your design. If no such folks are around, you can put up **smaller** pieces on codereview.stackexchange.com too

Comment: Well I found your answer acceptable so I figured I'd denote it as such. If differing opinions are presented I'll give them consideration all the same. As for reviewing, I don't have anyone for personal review to ask, and public review scares me a little, due to my lack of knowledge and therefore confidence... I will be uploading the library to GitHub soon anyway, so maybe I should just go ahead and try that site. Thank you for suggesting that, and taking time to answer my very base level question.

Comment: You are very welcome. And if you want to learn "how"/"what" you could place on codereview.SE ... just study the questions there; and see which ones gets upvotes, and what kind of answers come in. Then decide if you have smaller pieces that could fit in there.